# Checked Items in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I have a `CheckedListBox` with items from a database.
When I check an item in the `CheckedListBox` and after that I close the form and open the form again, the item is not checked any more, i.e. the "check" has not been saved.

How can I accomplish that if I check an item and then close the form and open it again, that the item is still checked?

I tried this:

```
 void deliveries_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < deliveries.ClbOrdersCheckDelivery.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (deliveries.ClbOrdersCheckDelivery.GetItemChecked(i) == true)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.CheckedItems = deliveries.ClbOrdersCheckDelivery.GetItemChecked(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

]\

Comment: You could use the application settings for this.

Comment: Yes Max, i edited my question , please look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

To save the settings.
Write it after the for loop.

**EDIT**

I tried the following code to save all checked items to settings file. It works. Please check.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.CheckedItems = string.Empty;
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.CheckedItems += item + "," ;
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Properties.Settings.Default.CheckedItems);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var checkedItems = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckedItems.ToString().Split(',');
        foreach (var item in checkedItems)
        {
            var index=checkedListBox1.FindString(item);
            if(index>=0)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's didn't work...
i think that the problem in:
  Properties.Settings.Default.CheckedItems = **deliveries.ClbOrdersCheckDelivery.GetItemChecked(i)**;

HELP PLEASE!

Comment: Anyways the save method should be called to persist changes to your settings. Also, I hope you are trying to save CheckItem not Items. Because your code would only save one item.

Comment: Thank you, but it's didn't work...
Which event did you chose? and What is the Type of "CheckedItems" in your App. settings?

Comment: Oh, I'm SORRY, I think that you aren't understant me, I mean how to save the "Check" In checkedlistbox like in that video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSCNVqVTlQ4
In that video he save the check in checkbox and not in checkedlistbox.

Comment: Bro, CheckBox and CheckedListBox are two different things. And both behave differently. CheckBox is usd at places where you want to give only one check to the user. Example: I agree to terms and conditions place. While the checked box list is given at places where you want the user to select multiple values. In your case, I m not sure, what you are looking for. But the code you posted was for checkedlistbox, hence my answer was based on checkedlistbox.

Comment: Yea, I need the same thing that in the video but on CheckedListBox.
I explain: I have a lot Orders Codes in the checkedlistbox that taken from DataBase, when i checked some orders in checkedlistbox (make thier value - true) and i exit the form , so when I reopen the form, the orders in the checkedlistbox return to be false and not true. 
So how i will do that Orders I MARKED in the Checkedlistbox return to be true when I reopen the form?
Thanks.

Comment: Please check the edited code. In the form load you can write the code to fetch Selected Items from Settings file and then check the selected check boxes.